# Change UITableView custom header view's button image not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a UIView using nib file. and set it as table view header view. In this view I have a button. I tried to change the button's image, but nothing changes.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        HealthPlanHeaderView *view = (HealthPlanHeaderView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([HealthPlanHeaderView class]) owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
        [view.addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editFood) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.healthPlanHeaderView = view;
        return view;
    }else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (void)editFood {
    self.healthEditing = !self.healthEditing;
    UIImage *image = self.healthEditing ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"finish"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit-button"];
    [self.healthPlanHeaderView.addButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I noticed the button image did set, but the button won't show newly set image, it remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you just need to invoke the tableView's reloadData to refresh it.